# Create a multicolor background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I'm a novice photoshop user, i stumbled upon the designs of the awesome mike of creativemints, and i noticed how his backgrounds are really beautiful and smooth, i tried to recreate it and failed miserably so my question is, how do you achieve such effect??

[image]

and thank you so much!!

Comment: A combination of gradients and gaussian blur, likely. Google to find plenty of examples/tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use a very large and soft paint brush to paint big blobs of color on top of a dark blue background and then blur it to achieve a soft gradient look. In your example image, this is most likely the technique.

1. Set your background to dark blue
2. Use a large paint brush (Shortcut: B) with hardness set to  0% (you can make brushes small/larger using the [ and ] keys, and softer/harder using SHIFT + [ or ])
3. On the background layer, paint big blobs of pink, teal and alternate
   green blues around the canvas
4. To achieve a very soft 'gradient' look, go to Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur with the Radius set to around 50px.

Here's an image I created with this technique.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, this is actually the right way to do it! i tried the gradients but it was too straight no matter how much ° ; thank you again i really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are serious about PS let me introduce you to your new best friend, the Gradient.

There are many ways of achieving a gradient and I'm gonna show you the one I prefer.

- Create a layer and fill it with white.
- Right click on it and select Blending Options
- Click and check Gradient overlay.
- Click on the color picker and select two or more colors and an angle.
- To get that effect you can use Blur under the Filter tab.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am!! and thank you for the quick response, I tried it and the result was pretty decent (better than using brushes!), i will keep exploring the tool and hope i achieve the desired result, thanks again!